# Why am I getting a 405 method not allowed error on a DELETE request for WebApi that works locally, after disabling webdav?

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, webdav, http-status-code-405

When I make a call to a WebApi DELETE endpoint, I am getting back a 405 error saying "The requested resource does not support http method 'DELETE'". This problem only happens in our staging environment, and everything works fine locally.

I know there are many questions on SE related to this problem, but believe I've tried all the standard solutions, including:

1) Confirming that my argument name matches my webapiconfig route setup:
`config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Default", "api/{controller}/{id}", new {id = RouteParameter.Optional});` is the route configuration and 
`public HttpActionResult Delete(int id)` is the controller method signature.

2) Trying both verb="*" and verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" in my Web.config `<handlers>` for url routing.

3) Adding `<remove name="WebDAVModule"/>` to `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">` and `<remove name="WebDAV"/>` to `<handlers>` in my Web.config. (I read through the article and tried copying the solution posted [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications), as well as several variants found on SE).

There is no Javascript involved in making the call, so that rules out the other common solution to this problem. Below is the system.webServer section of my web.config file as it now stands. Any thoughts?

`<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*."
verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
  </system.webServer>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for posterity's sake - the issue was actually with the IIS configuration on the staging and production machines. The filepath that IIS was pointing to was not the folder where Octopus was deploying the latest version of the site, but a folder that stored an older version. So the site was still up, but new code wasn't being used. The fixes I tried in the question were successful.